# How to CC the sender?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have code to send email. I'm struggling to CC the sender? If I mail I should get the CC, if my colleague mails he should get the CC.

Our usernames aren't firstname.lastname but our email addresses are.

```
Sub SendPDF()

Dim strPath As String, strFName As String
Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object

Title = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy") & " - " & ActiveSheet.Name & ""

strPath = Environ$("temp") & "\" 'Or any other path, but include trailing "\"

strFName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
strFName = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd") & " - " & ActiveSheet.Name & ".pdf"

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    strPath & strFName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "firstname.surname@email.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Title
    .body = "Please see attached"
    .Attachments.Add strPath & strFName
    '.Display
    .Send
End With

Kill strPath & strFName
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: what in fact do you need?...

Comment: sorry if it's not clear.  I want the above script to CC the from address

Comment: example: If I submitted the above it would also CC back to me

Comment: Have you tried the mailadress for CC there? ``.CC = "yourmail@mail.com"`

Comment: yes but there's going to be multiple users sending from this

Comment: try with this: `.CC = outApp.Session.Accounts(1)`

Comment: hasn't CC'd anyone off that

Comment: you still need to clarify...

Comment: sorry, it's just left the CC field blank

Comment: do you mean that automatically the mail is also send to the sender of the mail? E.g. if you mail you get the mail CC, if your colleague mail hi should get the mail CC?

Comment: yes that's correct katz

Comment: You would would probably need to use a Active Directory/ LDAP search to get the user's email address - but I think that's very much outside the scope of this question so I'm just suggesting in a comment....

Comment: do you use Outlook as you default mail programm? do you have your e-mail account set there?

Comment: yes we are using Outlook as the default mailing program

Comment: so, try: `cc=outApp.Session.Accounts(1).smtpaddress`

Comment: that doesn't work, is there anything I need to change in that?

Comment: both my proposals work for me ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CurrentUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869341(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Namespace class to get the currently logged-on user as a Recipient object. Then you can get the [Address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867602(v=office.15).aspx) property value which representing the e-mail address of the Recipient.

```
.CC = nameSpace.CurrentUser.Address;
```

Also you may find the [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/) article helpful.

Comment: Hi Eugene, I can't get that to work. it just blanks the CC field

Comment: .CC = nameSpace.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Address; Try exploring the AddressEntry for the CurrentUser.

Comment: Be aware that the above can cause the security warning regarding "Sending on behalf of,"

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub email()
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim rngTo As Range
    Dim rngCc As Range
    Dim rngBcc As Range
    Dim rngSubject As Range
    Dim rngAttach As Range
    Dim rngBody As Range

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rngTo = .Range("B1")
        Set rngCc = .Range("B2")
        Set rngBcc = .Range("B3")
        Set rngSubject = .Range("B4")
        Set rngAttach = .Range("B5")
        Set rngBody = .Range("B6")

    End With

    With objMail
        .To = rngTo.Value
        .Cc = rngCc.Value
        .Bcc = rngBcc.Value
        .Subject = rngSubject.Value
        .Attachments.Add rngAttach.Value
        .Body = rngBody.Value
        .Display
    End With

    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing
    Set rngTo = Nothing
    Set rngCc = Nothing
    Set rngBcc = Nothing
    Set rngSubject = Nothing
    Set rngAttach = Nothing
    Set rngBody = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add explanatory text why this solves the question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for high quality answering.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of old, but I ended up here, so someone else might!

I was able to get the sender CC'd using the namespace (at least in an exchange environment). In my case, the CurrentUser. The address returned a string like the following:

```
/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)/cn=Recipients/cn=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXX
```

This was resolved successfully, and successfully CC'd the sender.

Might also look at [Get sender's email address with Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922075/get-senders-email-address-with-excel-vba)

```
Sub TestCC()
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim OutNS As Outlook.Namespace

'   Get open Outlook, or create a new instance
    On Error Resume Next
    Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If OutApp Is Nothing Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

'   Get MAPI Namespace
    Set OutNS = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        
'   Create Mail Item
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'Item type 0

'   Build email
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
    
        .To = "first.last@email.com"
        .CC = OutNS.CurrentUser.Address
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Email Subject Line"
        .Body = "Body Text"
    
    '   Resolve added recipients
        .Recipients.ResolveAll
    
    '   Display or Send created email
        .Display
        '.Send
    
    End With

'   Clean up
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutNS = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```