# Get sender's SMTP email address with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I pull the Subject, received date and sender's name with the following code:

```
Set InboxSelect = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder
i = 0: EmailCount = 0
EmailCount = InboxSelect.Items.Count
While i < EmailCount
    i = i + 1
    blastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    LastRow = Sheets("Body").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    With InboxSelect.Items(i)
        MsgBox (SenderEmailAddress)
        'If .senderemailaddress = "*@somethingSpecific.co.uk" Then
            'EmailCount = EmailCount + 1
            Sheets("Import Data").Range("A" & blastRow).Formula = .SenderName
            Sheets("Import Data").Range("B" & blastRow).Formula = Format(.ReceivedTime, "dd/mm/yyyy")
            Sheets("Import Data").Range("C" & blastRow).Formula = .Subject
            Sheets("Body").Range("A" & LastRow).Formula = .Body
        'End If
    End With
Wend
```

What I'm trying to achieve now is an if statement that will say "If the sender's email address is 'anything@somethingSpecific.co.uk' then execute that code. 
I've tried SenderEmailAddress but it returns blank when tested in a message box.

EDIT: `/O=*SET1*/OU=FIRST ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=*VARIABLE1*` is now being returned in the immediate window every time with the below code:

```
Set InboxSelect = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder
i = 0: EmailCount = 0
EmailCount = InboxSelect.Items.Count
While i < EmailCount
    For Each Item In InboxSelect.Items
        Debug.Print Item.senderemailaddress
        If Item.senderemailaddress = "/O=SET1/OU=FIRST ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=*" Then
            i = i + 1
            blastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            LastRow = Sheets("Body").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            With InboxSelect.Items(i)
                    Sheets("Import Data").Range("A" & blastRow).Formula = .SenderName
                    Sheets("Import Data").Range("B" & blastRow).Formula = Format(.ReceivedTime, "dd/mm/yyyy")
                    Sheets("Import Data").Range("C" & blastRow).Formula = .Subject
                    'PASTING BODY IS SLOW
                    Sheets("Body").Range("A" & LastRow).Formula = .Body
                'End If
            End With
        End If
    Next Item
Wend
```

What I've attempted to do is use a wildcard symbol (the *) to act as the variation in the returned message but that hasn't worked, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You're correct, it should be the `SenderEmailAddress` property.

Comment: Am I using it correctly in that commented out If statement? Because that method doesn't work.

Comment: Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example of when using the `SenderEmailAddress` property returns the e-mail string as required.

```
Dim outlookApp As outlook.Application, oOutlook As Object
Dim oInbox As outlook.Folder, oMail As outlook.MailItem

Set outlookApp = New outlook.Application
Set oOutlook = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oInbox = oOutlook.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

For Each oMail In oInbox.Items
    Debug.Print oMail.SenderEmailAddress
Next oMail
```

**EDIT:**

The issue is that what the `.SenderEmailAddress` property is returning the `EX`  address, whereas we want the `SMTP` address. For any internal e-mail addresses, it will return the `EX` type address.

To get the `SMTP` address from an internal e-mail, you can use the below.

```
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application, oOutlook As Object
Dim oInbox As Outlook.Folder, oMail As Outlook.MailItem

Dim strAddress As String, strEntryId As String, getSmtpMailAddress As String
Dim objAddressentry As Outlook.AddressEntry, objExchangeUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser
Dim objReply As Outlook.MailItem, objRecipient As Outlook.Recipient

Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set oOutlook = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oInbox = oOutlook.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

For Each oMail In oInbox.Items
    If oMail.SenderEmailType = "SMTP" Then

        strAddress = oMail.SenderEmailAddress

    Else

        Set objReply = oMail.Reply()
        Set objRecipient = objReply.Recipients.Item(1)

        strEntryId = objRecipient.EntryID

        objReply.Close OlInspectorClose.olDiscard

        strEntryId = objRecipient.EntryID

        Set objAddressentry = oOutlook.GetAddressEntryFromID(strEntryId)
        Set objExchangeUser = objAddressentry.GetExchangeUser()

        strAddress = objExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress()

    End If

    getSmtpMailAddress = strAddress
    Debug.Print getSmtpMailAddress

Next oMail
```

If the e-mail is already `SMTP` it will just use the .SenderEmailAddress property to return the address. If the e-mail is `EX` then it will find the `SMTP` address by using the `.GetAddressEntryFromID()` Method.

The above is modified code from what I found on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854047/read-senders-email-address-from-ms-outlook-mail/16858032#16858032). [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184624(v=office.14).aspx) is also a link with how to do this within C#.

Comment: I can't seem to get to work in my code or on its own, how am I supposed to adapt it?
EDIT: I've noticed it's printing to the immediate window after some more tweaking but it's not returning the email address, I may be able to get this to work regardless. I'll post the code if I can, thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know why it's not returning any e-mail addresses - please do post your solution if you get it to work.

Comment: In the immediate window, I'm getting `/O=*SET1*/OU=FIRST ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=*VARIABLE1*` (I've had to omit some sensitive information, but all the returned code is always the same and 'variable1' is always different, as that's the sender.). I'll edit my question to explain what I need to do next.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use MailItem.Reply just to get to the sender object - Outlook 2010 and newer expose the MailItem.Sender property which returns the AddressEntry object.

Comment: Some of us haven't migrated onto 2010 yet ;). But still, thanks for the advice; I'll check it out when we move over onto 2010.

Comment: Wow, I've literally spent about 4 hours trying to figure out how to get the EX email address from a MeetingItem.  Lots and lots of googling later, I found your code.  GENIUS!  How in the world did you come up with that?  For the life of me, I couldn't figure this out ... easy for MailItem but NOT easy for MeetingItem.

Answer (score 6):

```
Public Function GetSenderAddrStr(objMail As Outlook.MailItem) As String
 If objMail.SenderEmailType = "SMTP" Then
        GetSenderAddrStr = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
 Else
        GetSenderAddrStr = objMail.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
 End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, the sender's SMTP address will be available in a separate property, you can access it using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor` - take a look at an existing message using [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - click IMessage button.

Otherwise you can use `ExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress`

Off the top of my head:

```
on error resume next 'PropertyAccessor can raise an exception if a property is not found
if item.SenderEmailType = "SMTP" Then
  strAddress = item.SenderEmailAddress
Else
  'read PidTagSenderSmtpAddress
  strAddress  = item.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001F")
  if Len(strAddress) = 0 Then
    set objSender = item.Sender
    if not (objSender Is Nothing) Then
      'read PR_SMTP_ADDRESS_W 
      strAddress  = objSender.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001F")
      if Len(strAddress) = 0 Then
        'last resort
        set exUser = objSender.GetExchangeUser
        if not (exUser Is Nothing) Then
          strAddress = exUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
        End If
      End If
    End If
  En If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just use send keys to force "Control+k" in outlook? Seems like this would solve your issue and probably make for an easy slice of code.

try adding this somewhere?

```
 Application.SendKeys("^k")       'i believe this is correct syntax, never used this yet but i think it works
```

Comment: Personally I would advise against using send keys; it's an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I'm trying to tell my code "If this email says 'anything@somethingSpecific.co.uk' then execute this code:". I can't figure out how to get VBA to read the domain.

Comment: @Iturner yeah its bad practice but if there's no other option you could make sure to set it specifically to outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing
`varTest = Item.senderemailaddress
            If InStr(varTest, "BE WISER INSURANCE") > 0 Then`

which detected the set section that wouldn't be in any emails I didn't want. Thanks very much for your help, @Iturner!

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the sender's SMTP address will be available on the mesage itself in a separate property (`PidTagSenderSmtpAddress` = `0x5D01001F`, DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001F"`), you can access it using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor` - take a look at an existing message using [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - click IMessage button.

Otherwise you can use `ExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress`: it is more expensive than reading the `PidTagSenderSmtpAddress` property. `PidTagSenderSmtpAddress` will also work if `ExchangeUser` fails (which can happen if the user was deleted from GAL or if you are looking at the message in a profile different from the one where the message was created)

Off the top of my head:

```
on error resume next 'PropertyAccessor can raise an exception if a property is not found
if item.SenderEmailType = "SMTP" Then
  strAddress = item.SenderEmailAddress
Else
  'read PidTagSenderSmtpAddress
  strAddress  = item.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001F")
  if Len(strAddress) = 0 Then
    set objSender = item.Sender
    if not (objSender Is Nothing) Then
      'read PR_SMTP_ADDRESS_W 
      strAddress  = objSender.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001F")
      if Len(strAddress) = 0 Then
        'last resort
        set exUser = objSender.GetExchangeUser
        if not (exUser Is Nothing) Then
          strAddress = exUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
        End If
      End If
    End If
  En If
End If
```