# SenderEmailAddress property does not contain a standard email address for internal contacts

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

**Background:**

Using an Outlook Rule to trigger a script, I want all of my email from certain high-visibility clients to open immediately upon receipt.

I have successfully set up a rule that triggers when those clients send me email. It looks something like this:

[image: emails from Jobs and Wozniak]

And I have successfully created a script that opens a reply to the email, depending on who sent it. It looks something like this:

```
Sub OpenEmailImmediately(oEmail As Outlook.MailItem)

    Select Case oEmail.Sender
        Case "Jobs, Steve"
            oEmail.Reply.Display
    End Select

End Sub
```

Although this works, I have implemented it using `.Sender` property.

**Problem:**

I would *prefer* to implement this using the sender's email address (a unique value associated with every email I receive). Unfortunately, `oEmail.SenderEmailAddress`, which I expected to contain the email address, *only worked for external clients*.

While troubleshooting, I discovered that where I expected `oEmail.SenderEmailAddress` to have a value similar to this:

> steve.jobs@apple.com

for internal emails it had a value similar to this:

> /O=APPLE/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=JOBSS6738

**Question:**

Is there a way I can make this script work for internals *and* externals using their standard email address?

**Code with implemented solution:**

Using Dmitry's answer below, the code was modified to use the email address:

```
Sub OpenEmailImmediately(oEmail As Outlook.MailItem)

    If oEmail.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
        Select Case oEmail.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
            Case "steve.jobs@apple.com"
                oEmail.Reply.Display
        End Select
    Else
        Select Case oEmail.SenderEmailAddress
            Case "tom.brady@patriots.com"
                oEmail.Reply.Display
        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get sender's email address with Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922075/get-senders-email-address-with-excel-vba)

Comment: This is not the same question, and although they both work with .SenderEmailAddress the nuance is different. In my opinion, hiding and closing this question will be a disservice to the community.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a perfectly valid address of type "EX" (as opposed to SMTP) - check the value of the `MailItem.SenderEmailType` property. If it is "SMTP", use `MailItem.SenderEmailAddress`. If it is "EX", use `MailItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress`.

You can also try to read `PidTagSenderSmtpAddress` MAPI property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001F`) using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` - take a look at the message with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author - click IMessage button) or [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi).