# Is there a way to find/read the Sender Email Address using R, RDCOMClient

Tags: r, email, outlook, sender, rdcomclient

```
library("tm")
library("NLP")
library("dplyr")
library("readtext")
library("readxl")
library("foreach")
library("devtools")
library("RDCOMClient")
library("rlist")

WDF = vector()
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outlookNameSpace = OutApp$GetNameSpace("MAPI")

folderName = "Folder Name"
fld <- outlookNameSpace$GetDefaultFolder(6)
fld = fld$folders(folderName)
Cnt = fld$Items()$Count()
emails <- fld$items
df = data.frame(sno = 1:Cnt,Text = "",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for(i in 1:10){
  d = as.data.frame(emails(i)$Body(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  df$Text[i] = d[1]
  df$Sender[i] = emails(i)[['SenderName']]
  df$To[i] = emails(i)[['To']]
  df$sub[i] = emails(i)[['subject']]
}
emails(2)[['SenderName']]
```

I'm trying to get the senders Email Address by using following code :

```
emails(2)[['SenderEmailAddress']]
```

But it ends up giving like this :

```
[1] "/O=EXCHANGELABS/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=E4CD239AB9F44AC4AC0A4015B6F4805A-RATINGSDIRE"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that exchange stores the sender address as either the normal smtp version of the address for external users, but for Exchange users it uses the MS Exchange address. To get the normal smtp address, you have to look up the exchange user on and get their normal smtp email address.

You may want to look at the `extrospectr` package on github. I haven't used it but it looks like it would give you a clean inbox like you're looking for.

If you look at the `.lookup_exchange_sender` function in the file `read_inbox.R` it shows how they handled looking up the address. First you have to look at what type of user the `Sender` is (which you can do by retrieving the `Sender` property of the MailItem, and then the [AddressEntryUserType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser.addressentryusertype) property, which has [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oladdressentryusertype) enumeration). This ends up like `emails(2)$Sender()$AddressEntryUserType()`.

Then then if it's an Exchange user, you would need to get the `Sender` property of the MailItem (which is an [AddressEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry)) and then use the `GetExchangeUser` method on the AddressEntry to return an [ExchangeUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser) object. Once you have that you just need to access the PrimarrySMTPAddress property of the ExchangeUser. 
When you put it all together, it looks like this: `emails(2)$Sender()$GetExchangeUser()$PrimarySMTPAddress()`.

Link to `extrospectr` on github:
https://github.com/aecoleman/extrospectr

This explains the Outlook methodology for what's stored in the sender email property:
[SenderEmailAddress property does not contain a standard email address for internal contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36900156/senderemailaddress-property-does-not-contain-a-standard-email-address-for-intern)

Comment: Thanks to @AColeman for edits to improve my answer and for creating the `extrospectr` package

Comment: I'm glad it came in handy! @Parth Kalra, please accept this answer if it solves your issue, or provide details as to the errors or issues that you receive when trying to implement it on your machine.

Comment: @Roger-123 Thank you this was really helpful.

Comment: @AColeman  Using the same solution mentioned it works, but it's taking a long long time, when we have a big list to find. Currently I'm having >50k email id's to scan for. Is there any way to make it more robust ?

Comment: @Roger-123 can you help make it more robust ? it's taking long time, let's say 1 to 2 sec for 1 ID.

Comment: Could you create a new question and post the updated code with a request on how to speed it up?  That's probably a clearer path to understanding the issue and getting it resolved. Just post the new link in the comments here.